# "Xamarin Test Recorder quit unexpectedly" on Mac when trying to open test (.xtrs file)

Tags: android, testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios, recorder

I just installed Xamarin Test Recorder and started using it, I've recorded and run tests against my android app, and I've saved that test. 
However, if I try to open a test (by double clicking the .xtrs file) it always pops up this error:

> **Xamarin Test Recorder quit unexpectedly.**
>   Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and
>   send a report to Apple.

[image]

I've tried creating another test and got exactly the same result (create and run and save works fine but the file cannot be opened again after having closed Xamarin Test Recorder).

This seems like an amazing tool and I'd love to use it; has anyone come accross this issue and can suggest a fix.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version 1.0.2 (1.0)

Comment: I'm on 1.0.3 (dev channel) and but have not seen that issue with 1.0.2 either... Make sure you only have one XTR installed and thus when clicking on a `.xtrs` session file it is opening the latest version. Highlight a `.xtrs` and  `Cmd-I` to get the file info, go down to `Open With`, open the dropdown and might sure the XTR that is begin opened is v1.0.2... if not select the correct one and make sure you click `Change All`

Comment: The 'Open with' is set to (1.0.2), it is the only XTR version I have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I downloaded the latest version and it worked.
**From https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/**

I also found the Xamarin email support gave quick responses : [support@xamarin.com](http://mailto:support@xamarin.com)